# Adding segment to Bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

When I attempt to add a second segment to a Bezier curve, it creates it very small and folded back on itself, almost like a circle. I create it by selecting the end point of the first curve and then Ctrl + LMB. I've tried this is 2.77 and 2.78c and get the same results so it's obviously something I'm doing wrong. Trying to find the new end point is difficult and when I do hit on it and drag it away, it generally wanders off the flat plane. Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the handle type of the newly created segment to *Vector* from the toolshelf. Also check if the new curve is closed from the *Properties Window* in the *Object Data* tab

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to use the `Extrude` operation.  Select the last control point on the curve and hit <kbd>e</kbd>.  You can then move your mouse around to choose where the new control point will go.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solve my issue

Comment: `E` for [Extend](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Intro_to_Bezier_Curves#Extending_Your_Curve) (not extrude)

Answer (score 1):

I was finally successful in adding a second bezier curve, but not the way described in a Blender course I'm taking. If I do it the instructor's way, I get a curve folded back on itself with very little chance of straightening it out.

I'm using Blender v2.78c but I tried it on 2.77 and got the same results.

Here is how I have found I can do it.

At the end of the first bezier curve align the control handle so that one end points generally in the direction that you want to add the next curve. Select (RMD) the END of the control handle which points in that direction (NOT the end point of the curve), hold down CTRL and left click (LMB). The new curve will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Years in the future from the original answer but I hope this helps others. Version 2.79 you can make local (L) that let's you scale, rotate, move you can adjust any modifiers apply and in theory it should be still link to the external file.